# How to read content from a file , uploaded using "Input Type" = file in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple HTML form, where I have a field with browse button for uploading local files.

When fetching the uploaded file's path, it is showing as `C:/fakepath/filename.xls`. I came to know that it is the browser security that is not allowing to read exact file path from local Computer.

Is there any way that I can read contents from the Uploaded file.

```
<input type="file" id = "FilePath" name="FilePath" size="18">
```

So when I do `document.getElementById("FilePath")`. I got `C:/fakepath/filename.xls`.

Can anyone please help how to read file content from uploaded file

Comment: Are you trying to read it in client-side JS or on your server?

Comment: I am trying to read it from Client Side JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [HTML5 File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications).

Comment: Specifically the `files` property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#files and `FileReader` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following URL as a reference to read the file using js.

[reference](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)