How to use a file upload input as a variable (HTML)?
I am working on an emulator remix right now where at the moment in order to select games you need to actually go into the code and change some lines in addition to uploading the file directly to the file directory. I want to make it so that you can just launch the website and select a file there to use as the ROM for the emulator.
Code looks like this so far (With the two sections of <div>):
<div id="start">
    <input type="file" id="fileUrl" name="fileUrl" accept=".gba"/>
</div>
<div id='Window'>
    <div style='width:100%;height:100%;max-width:100%'>
        <div id='game'></div>
    </div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        EJS_player = '#game';
        EJS_core = 'gba';
        EJS_gameUrl = <getValue id="fileUrl"/>;
        EJS_pathtodata = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethanaobrien/emulatorjs@main/data';
    </script>
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethanaobrien/emulatorjs@main/data/loader.js'>
    </script>
</div>

I don't know what I was expecting but I put in a <input> element on a different page but can't find a way to make it into a variable which can be used in my "game_url = ___" section. I would also need to make it so that once you submit the file to the upload, it switches the page to the actual emulator one. I also tried putting the two sections into different <div> chunks and used a <getValue> in the game_url thing. (I'm using replit if that helps.)
UPDATE: I got the file upload button to appear, and take the file, now I just need it to reload the game window to apply the file to the emulator, I also would like to make it so that it hides the file input div.
Code is now:
<div>
    <var id='file'>
        <input type='file' id='fileURL';>
    </var>
</div>
<div style='width:100%;height:100%;max-width:100%'>
    <div id='game'></div>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    EJS_player = '#game';
    EJS_core = 'gba';
    EJS_gameUrl = file;
    EJS_pathtodata = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethanaobrien/emulatorjs@main/data';
</script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethanaobrien/emulatorjs@main/data/loader.js'>
</script>


You could turn it into a ObjectURL and use that

You'll need to handle the change event for the file input, and then create an object URL for the first file.  However, I don't know anything about your emulator API and why it just wants global variables set.  Is there no way to initialize it later?

"I would also need to make it so that once you submit the file to the upload, it switches the page to the actual emulator one" - yes, do that. You can't put these in different pages (at different locations) without involving a server. Just handle the submit event, read the file and render the emulator page in that handler function. You cannot just put that code in a top-level <script>.

This question feels like it should have many, many duplicates… and yet every single one I look at seems so poor. Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/q/56362702/3840170 is the best, and it’s not great either.
